# Если писать методы в таком стиле это не нарушает паттерн "Repository"?

Tags: javascript, шаблоны-проектирования, repository

В своем проекте я разделяю бизнес логику и обращение к бд на 3 слоя:

- Сервисы (Бизнес логика);
- Репозиторий (Они максимально тупые и кроме того как передать данные модели и отдать данные сервису через маппинг ничего не умеют);
- Модель (Сущность описанная через ORM); Использую ORM Sequelize

user.service.js

```
const findById = async (id) => {
   if (!id) throw Error('Id не передан');

   const user = await UserRepo.findById(id);
 
   if (!user) throw Error('User не найден');

   return user;
}
```

user.repository.js

```
const findById = (id) => User.findByPk(id);
```

И тут появилась задача, когда мне нужно одним запросом проверить по email, login. Если я создам вот такой метод это будет некорректным решением в плане принципа паттерна Repository?: 
user.service.js

```
const findByParams = async (condition) => {
  if (!condition) throw Error('condition не передан');

  const user = await UserRepo.findByParams(condition);

   if (!user) throw Error('User не найден');

   return user;
}
```

user.repository.js

```
const findById = (id) => User.findByPk(id);
const findByParams = (condition) => User.findOne(condition);
```

index.js

```
// Например
const user = await UserService.findByParams({where: {login, email } });
```

Или стоит лучше создать вот такой метод?:

```
// user.service.js
const findByLoginAndEmail = async (login, email) => {
   if (!login) throw Error('Логин не передан');
   if (!email) throw Error('Email не передан');

   const user = await UserRepo.findByLoginAndEmail(login, email);

   if (!user) throw Error('User не найден');

   return user;
}

// user.repository.js
const findByLoginAndEmail = (login, email) => User.findOne({ where: { login, email } });
```

Есть какие мысли?

Comment: методы `findById` и `findByParams` вполне могли бы размещаться в каком-то общем сервисе, параметризируемый моделями, ну а `findByLoginAndEmail`хорошо ложится в канву `user.repository`, но если честно плохо понятно что именно Вас беспокоит. Думаете что от пары стрелочных функций `user.repository` сильно "поумнеет"?

Comment: @DaniilLoban скорее волнует то что метод findByParams становится универсальным и возможно смысла от репозитория уже нет. Но если даже и оставить репозиторий, то при смене ORM, который принимает объекты в другом формате придется переписывать/дописывать логику в каждом репозиторий, чтобы преобразовать этот объект в нужный формат. Например сейчас: { where: {login, email} }, и при смене ORM нужно будет делать так { where: [login, email] }

Comment: я бы тогда предпочел сделать обобщенный сервис `wrapper` для поставщика данных, кастомизируемый через `инъекцию зависимостей`, лично я ничего плохого в универсальных методах не вижу если это не снижает производительность, в данном случае - все ок. Думаю, что любые паттерны прежде всего полезны когда позволяют в дальнейшем без особых трудностей расширять код, `wrapper` с обобщенным интерфейсом позволил бы дописывать поддержку различных `ORM` если это будет необходимою